# ERROR ITMS-90283: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle <com.domain.s> [com.domain.s/name.app] is invalid

Tags: javascript, ios, electron, nuxt.js, mac-app-store

sorry I'm new to electron and Mac app store. I having some issue when uploading the electron app to Mac app store using transporter. I already created the Provisioning Profile and install certificate for Mac Installer distribution and Mac App distribution. But still having the same error. Please help

ERROR ITMS-90283: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle com.domain.desktop [com.domain.desktop.pkg/Payload/appname.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate.] For more information, visit the macOS Developer Portal."